# React big calendar hide start time end time from time slot

Tags: reactjs, react-big-calendar

I have a react big calendar as in teh picture below, and I want to remove the circled strat-time/end time:

[image: img]

The react big calendare is rendered with this parameters:

```
<BigCalendar
                selectable
                events={this.props.events?this.props.events:[]}
                views={{ week:MyWeek}}
                defaultView='week'
                defaultDate={this.state.date?this.state.date:new Date()}
                date={this.state.date?this.state.date:new Date()}
                now={new Date(0)}
                min={new Date(this.state.today.getFullYear(), this.state.today.getMonth(), this.state.today.getDate(), 8)}
                max={new Date(this.state.today.getFullYear(), this.state.today.getMonth(), this.state.today.getDate(), 20)}
                onSelectSlot={(slotInfo) => {this.props.onSelectSlot('interview', slotInfo, 'add'); store.dispatch(addBreadcrumb({name: B_PREPARATION_INTERVIEW}));}}
                onSelectEvent={event => {this.props.onSelectEvent('interview', event); store.dispatch(addBreadcrumb({name: B_PREPARATION_INTERVIEW}));} }
                onNavigate={(date) => this.changeDate(date)}
                components={{event: Event }}
                eventPropGetter={(this.eventStyleGetter)}
                titleAccessor={function(e) {console.log("aaaaaaaaaaa"); console.log(e); return e.title;}}
            />
```

I tried to add titleAccessor to remove the start time/end time but with no result.

Answer (score 10):

You can override the CSS class `rbc-event-label` like so:

```
.rbc-event-label {
  display: none;
}
```

to hide the start and end times.

Answer (score 4):

Following the formats section in the [documentation](http://jquense.github.io/react-big-calendar/examples/index.html#popup):

```
const formats = {
    eventTimeRangeFormat: () => { 
      return "";
    },
  };
```

```
<Calendar formats={formats} />
```

Comment: Is it possible to get the current event in `eventTimeRangeFormat` and return something based on information in the current event?

Answer (score 1):

In `format.eventTimeRangeFormat` returns null, this will not show the time label.

[Check the documentation](http://intljusticemission.github.io/react-big-calendar/examples/index.html#prop-formats.eventTimeRangeFormat)

Comment: The built in tooltip uses `eventTimeRangeFormat` though. Removing it would cause the tooltip to be `: <event title>` cause it keeps the colon between the time and title.

Comment: Broken documentation link.

Answer (score 0):

```
 components={{
          day: {
            header: () => null,
          },
       }}
```

*in  react big calendar there is a prop called **component** inside .we have a prop called **day** in that **header: () => null**  time slot will hide . Link [enter link description here](https://jquense.github.io/react-big-calendar/examples/index.html?path=/story/about-big-calendar--page)*